# Which Cordova files do I need to check in to Configuration Management

Tags: cordova

I created a Cordova project and I see the following folders below . Which folders do I need to save  in my CM (TFS)?. Do I have to checkin all files

Folders

-- MyProject

```
-- bower.json

-- config.xml

 -- hooks

-- platform

   -- iOS
      -- build
      --myProject.xcodeproj
      -- ...

 -- android
    -- AndroidManifest.xml
    -- build
    -- build.gradle
    -- etc,,,
 -- browser
 -- platform.xml
 -- plugins
 -- res
 -- www
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: generally the files in the `platforms/*` are build artifacts from `cordova build <platform>`.

Comment: ok,, but how do you handle any changes to build.grade file or any changes made to the manifest